# Наследование. Одинаковые имена переменной в родителе и интерфейсе

Tags: java, наследование, интерфейс

Как указать компилятору к полю родителя или интерфейса обратиться?

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(B.s1); //ошибка
    }
}
interface Int {  String  s1 = "Int";}
class A {static  String  s1 = "A";}
class B extends A implements Int{}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что касается вопроса, то никак не указать: переменная, объявленная в интерфейсе не может быть переопределена.
Соответственно: вы пытаетесь обратиться к переменной, которая ссылается на 2 разных объекта.
Вот, [отличное объяснение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053596/compiler-error-reference-to-call-ambiguous)

Answer (score 1):

И в том и в другом случае вы объявляете статическую переменную. Соответственно используйте имя класса/интерфейса, в котором вы объявили переменную.

```
Int.s1
```